# Sublime 2, how to auto close HTML tags and place cursor inside the tag

Tags: html, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I'm trying to figure out how to get Sublime 2 to create the following behavior:

Type

```
<strong
```

then, upon typing `>`

Sublime will then immediately print

```
<strong></strong>
```

And then your cursor will be placed inside of the tag.

I feel like it did this automatically not more than a few months ago, or maybe I was just hallucinating, or was using a different bundle... but regardless, is there a setting or script I can build that will perform this tag behavior that Aptana gets 100% right but for some reason no other text editor can catch on to?

Comment: Clarification: You do _not_ want tab completion, [snippets](https://tutsplus.com/lesson/your-first-snippet/), or [zen coding](https://tutsplus.com/lesson/zen-coding-2/), but instead similar behavior to the quote auto-printing stuff.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> (in Mac) / <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> (in Windows)
2. type "strong"
3. <kbd>TAB</kbd>

Comment: You can also remap this is you want. I'm not a huge fan of CTRL so I changed it to super(command or windows)+shift+o. Just change it in your user key bindings file and do a search in the default first to make sure you're not overriding some other command they have by default. Hence, why I use o since that pattern is unused elsewhere.

Comment: On windows, this auto makes a `<p></p>` tag, and does not finish it. Tab did exactly what was requested.

Answer (score 4):

To get auto-complete of HTML in sublime text 2 I had follow this step :-

***open sublime -> view -> syntax -> HTML***

I hope this will provide you auto-complete of sublime.

Comment: TAB is not a reasonable substitute for this. I'm looking to emulate Aptana's tag functionality which is best for natural typing.

Comment: @Jasconius How is Olle Sjorgren's suggestions not superior to yor mazar's? Instead of the awkward CTRL + SHIFT + W, you just write your first tag, and then before the > press TAB. Seems much easier IMO.