# Auto closing HTML tags in Sublime Text 3

Tags: html, autocomplete, sublimetext3

> [Sublime 2, how to auto close HTML tags and place cursor inside the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13456756/sublime-2-how-to-auto-close-html-tags-and-place-cursor-inside-the-tag)
>
> I'm trying to figure out how to get Sublime 2 to create the following behavior:
>
> Type
>
> `<strong`
>
> then, upon typing >
>
> Sublime will then immediately print
>
> `<strong></strong>`
>
> And then your cursor will be placed inside of the tag.

I'm trying to do what's quoted above in Sublime Text 3. A similar question was also asked [here](https://superuser.com/questions/801357/sublime-text-3-automatically-close-html-tags) but an answer was lacking. Given the time past, I'm asking again. Basically I want to emulate how tags are completed on Codecademy, automatically, i.e. **without shortcuts (NO TAB)**.

[Codeacademy example.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfrrU.gif)

Comment: Clearly indicated **without shortcuts (NO TAB)** in bold, and the first answer literally say tab. Please read the question...

Comment: Any luck on that one?
I would like to have the same behavior as with brackets, quote marks etc.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me. It closes on a backslash, ie your close tag.

For example, you have `<div>my div<` and upon typing `/`, you will get `<div>my div</div>`.

To enable, add the following object to the array in the key binding file (Sublime Text > Preferences > Key Bindings).

```
 {
    "keys": ["/"],
    "command": "close_tag",
    "args": { "insert_slash": true },
    "context": [
        {
            "key": "selector",
            "operator": "equal",
            "operand": "(text.html, text.xml, meta.jsx.js) - string - comment",
            "match_all": true
        },
        {
            "key": "preceding_text",
            "operator": "regex_match",
            "operand": ".*<$",
            "match_all": true
        },
        { "key": "setting.auto_close_tags" }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not really the answer you want but if you type `</` ST3 will auto complete the closest unclosed tag. Otherwise the auto complete answer by Nick is your best bet.

Comment: This works by default **only** if the document syntax is set to `HTML`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in windows and may people in several forums suggested me to remove and reinstall Sublime 3. But issue not resolved. I don't know the cause of issue. it seems some problem occurred with the packages installed or settings configured. I got resolved the issue in this way by removing installed packages and settings.

**In Windows 10**

go to C:\Users\ YOUR_USER_NAME \AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3

Remove folders and contents from that folder it will resolve this issue.

**In Linux**

Please reverse the process described in https://packagecontrol.io/installation

> There is some issue coursing with this is that all the installed
>   packages will get removed. You need to reinstall needful packages
>   again.

So please make sure to note down and reinstall all the plugins needed.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the best work around for Sublime 3 that I have found is to go ahead and install the [SublimeCodeIntel](http://sublimecodeintel.github.io/SublimeCodeIntel/) package. I'm not sure if it's an issue with generating popups because the keybindings as given within the package are not working, but what is definitely working is multi lang auto suggest after typing `<_` (where _ is whitespace) as well as when you use the auto-suggest the closing tag auto generates.

Answer (score 1):

There's a plugin that will auto-close tags like you describe called [Auto Close](https://github.com/sh4nks/auto_close). It works for both Sublime 2 and 3.

Just be aware that it doesn’t work for JSX, and the package doesn’t appear to be maintained, but it does the job for me so hopefully it might help.

You can install it via Package Control by searching for "Auto Close".

Answer (score -1):

On Sublime Text 3 save any file as .html file.

Then typing something like:

followed by TAB key automatically expand to:

with complete tags of title , body and head.

Comment: Please note that the question author has asked for a solution that, and I quote, operates "**without shortcuts (NO TAB).**", and possibly update your answer accordingly.

Answer (score -2):

Heres the official documentation 
https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/auto_complete.html 
Its the same in most IDE's. Aslong as you have the settings enabled (as shown in the document)
it is then:
 CTRL+Space -  to show suggestions 
Enter to apply suggestion. (you can change that in the settings)

Answer (score -2):

On Sublime Text 3 save blank new file as .html file.

Then typing something like:

`<strong>`

followed by TAB key automatically expand to:

`<strong> </strong>`

with active cursor inside the tag

Comment: `tab`does more than just close tags - its an autocomplete feature. So typing `<inpu`and tabbing will result in `<input type="" name="">`, and not, `<input />`, for example. i.e. if all you want to do is have the tag automatically close this isn't the way to do it.